# How do I get the generic class property in python

Tags: python, generics

I have a class like:

```
class ExampleClass(BaseClass[Someclass]):
  pass


class BaseClass(AbstractBaseClass, Generic[T]):
  pass
```

I want to be able to do something like `ExampleClass.targetType` where I will return `Someclass.__name__` how can I do this inside `BaseClass` I cannot seem to do `T.__name__`

I can workaround by defining a method like

```
class ExampleClass(BaseClass[Something]):
    version = 1

    def get_target_class_name() -> str:
        return Something.__name__
```

But I will need to copy this for every class

Answer (score 9):

You can define a metaclass:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class AbstractBaseClass:
    pass

class BaseClassMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        assert "target_type" not in attrs
        if len(attrs["__orig_bases__"]) == 1:
            base, = attrs["__orig_bases__"]
            if args := getattr(base, "__args__", None):
                cls.target_type = args
        return super().__init__(name, bases, attrs)

class BaseClass(AbstractBaseClass, Generic[T], metaclass=BaseClassMeta):
    pass

class TargetClass():
    pass

class ExampleClass(BaseClass[TargetClass]):
    pass

print(ExampleClass().target_type) # TargetClass
```

This will make all subclasses of BaseClass that have a single superclass which has a single generic parameter have an attribute `target_type`, set to that parameter. This will be available to instances of the class too, and subclasses.

Comment: Can you explain why you're implementing `__init__` instead of `__new__` on the metaclass? Most examples for metaclasses implement `__new__` and i'm confused

Comment: Because I don't want to modify the type of the class that was created, so `__new__` should return an instance of BaseClassMeta as usual. It is possible to move the logic from `__init__` to `__new__` but since it is initialization, not instantiation logic, it makes more sense in `__init__`. But it doesn't matter that much.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [`typing.get_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_origin) and [`__orig_bases__`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0560/#mro-entries).

`get_args` will give you the arguments of a type:

```
assert get_args(Dict[int, str]) == (int, str)
```

and `__orig_bases__` stores the original bases as a tuple. In the context of the example code below

```
assert Derived.__orig_bases__ == (Base[int],)
```

so the resulting code would be something like:

```
from abc import ABC
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, get_args

T = TypeVar("T")


class Base(ABC, Generic[T]):
    def target_type(self) -> str:
        return get_args(self.__orig_bases__[0])[0].__name__


class Derived(Base[int]):
    pass


d = Derived()
print(d.target_type())
# prints 'int'
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that without duplication, add a method that retrieves the name of the type parameter to `BaseClass`.

### Example

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, get_args

T = TypeVar('T')

class BaseClass(Generic[T]):
    def get_target_class_name(self) -> str:
        return self.__orig_bases__[0].__args__[0].__name__
```

`typing.get_args` is used to retrieve the type arguments of the class. and since the type argument is a single argument in this case, we access it with index `[0]` and then access the `__name__` attribute to get the name of the class.

Now, use `get_target_class_name` in `ExampleClass` without needing to redefine it for each class:

```py
class Someclass:
    pass

class ExampleClass(BaseClass[Someclass]):
    pass

example_instance = ExampleClass()
target_type_name = example_instance.get_target_class_name()
print(target_type_name)  # Output: "Someclass"
```

Comment: @MarkDickinson thanks for pointing this out, I have fixed the error in example given

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it like this, maybe it helps you too:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class AbstractBaseClass:
    pass

class BaseClass(AbstractBaseClass, Generic[T]):
    
    @property
    def target_type(self) -> str:
        return self.__class__.__orig_bases__[0].__args__[0].__name__

class Someclass():
    pass

class ExampleClass(BaseClass[Someclass]):
    pass

    
print(ExampleClass().target_type)
# Someclass
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited/Modified**

I can propose another approach. Here we don't use the metaclass, but use a class decorator.

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')

def add_target_class_name(cls):
    def get_target_class_name(self):
        return cls.__name__
    cls.get_target_class_name = get_target_class_name
    return cls

class BaseClass(Generic[T]):
    print("Hello from BaseClass")

class Someclass:
    print("Hello from Someclass")

@add_target_class_name
class ExampleClass(BaseClass[Someclass]):
    def print_message(self):
        target_class_name = self.get_target_class_name()
        print("Target class name:", target_class_name)

example_instance = ExampleClass()

example_instance.print_message()
```

Output

```bash
Hello from BaseClass
Hello from Someclass
Target class name: ExampleClass
```

I think this approach can be seen as a reusable solution where we use decorators.